# JavaScript: Different results of JSON.stringify(object) and String(object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, stringify

I have an array of strings, and a productId that is a type of object

```
productIds = [ '61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219', '61c08d910579b11c103ba3b5' ];

productId = 61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219;
```

The productId is a value from MongoDB which the field is type Object.Schema.ObjectId

Now, I want to check if `productId` is in `productIds`. Hence, I need to convert/parse productId to string.

Why is it that the code below results in **true**

```
productIds.includes(String(productId))
productIds[0] === String(productId)
```

While the code below results in **false**

```
productIds.includes(JSON.stringify(productId))
productIds[0] === JSON.stringify(productId)
```

Here is also the output of me testing each type

```
[ '61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219', '61c08d910579b11c103ba3b5' ] | 61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219 is type of object

productIds.includes(String(orderedProduct._product) true
productIds.includes(JSON.stringify(orderedProduct._product)) false

61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219 is a typeof object 61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219 is a typeof string
true using string String(61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219)
false using stringify JSON.stringify(61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219)
```

Comment: `productId = 61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219` is invalid javascript. If `productId` is a string, then `JSON.stringify()` adds additional quotes around the the string.

Comment: Did you log  the result of `JSON.stringify`? (it explicitly wraps the string in double quotes). But the point is productId (despite your incorrect typing of it here) is probably a string already.

Comment: Sorry for that confusion, anyway the productId is just a value from a specific property of an object returned by mongoose 
{ ..., orderedProducts: [..., { _product: ObjectId("61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219") }]

Answer (score 2):

> productId = 61b8b4a7ebffe000ec619219;

That's a syntax error.

But leaving that aside:

`String` converts the value you pass to it into a string.

`JSON.stringify` converts the value you pass to it into string containing a JSON representation of that value.

In JSON, strings are delimited with `"`.

```js
const data = "foo";

const string = String(data);
const json = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(string);
console.log(json);
```

The differences with other data types become more pronounced:

```js
const data = { "an": "object" };

const string = String(data);
const json = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(string);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: I understand, I will keep this in mind. Thanks!